# Missing required parameter for Route

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Распространённая проблема  "Missing required parameter for Route", но у меня она немного иная, решение которой я просто никак не могу найти:

Вот мои связанные роуты:

```
Route::get('/monitoring/{monitoring}/edit', [HistoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('monitoring.edit');
Route::patch('/monitoring/{monitoring}', [HistoryController::class, 'update'])->name('monitoring.update');
```

обычный роут апдейта по документации laravel

Вот нужная часть контроллера:

```
public function edit(History $history) {
    return view('monitoring.edit', compact('history'));        
}
public function update(History $history, Request $request) {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'blablabla1' => 'integer',
        'blablabla2' => 'string',
        'blablabla3' => 'string',
        'blablabla4' => 'string',
    ]);
    dd($data);
}
```

ну и вьюшка:

```
<form class="container" action="{{route('monitoring.update', $history)}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('patch')
...
```

я ничего не придумывал, просто "следую по учебнику", однако у меня возникает ошибка, которая возникает при отсутствии аргумента - у меня же аргумент явно указывается. Что не так?

Comment: там в роуте точно `{monitoring}` должно быть а не `{history}` ?

Comment: в таком случае он почему-то выдает 404 при переходе по ссылке, хотя ссылка указана верно:{history}/edit

Comment: казалось бы верно должно быть `/monitoring/123/edit`, где 123 это условный ПК от объекта `history` ?

Comment: Да, должно быть так(

Answer (score 1):

В **web.php** заменить имя параметра с **monitoring** на **history**:

```
Route::get('/monitoring/{history}/edit', [HistoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('monitoring.edit');
```

В **HistoryController** так:

```
public function edit(History $history) {
    return view('monitoring.edit', compact('history'));        
}
```

Тогда должно всё работать, но если вы говорите что он отдаёт 404, значит у Вас в БД нет такой записи с **$history** проверьте, существует ли такая запись с переданным **ID** в БД